# Amazon S3 Bucket Policy - Filter by User Agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So .. I have an Amazon S3 bucket that I would like to serve up some files via http to an application server.  In order to secure this up going to set a specific user agent set as well as a limit on IP.

Here is what I've done

a) Created a new bucket called "my-test-bucket"

b) Set the bucket to "Enable website hosting"

c) Added a simple index.html to the bucket

d) Set the following bucket policy to test connectivity (wide open to zee internet)

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Id": "S3PolicyId1",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Public",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket/*"
    }
]
}
```

d) Tested and it works!

e) Set the bucket policy to limit the user agent

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Id": "S3PolicyId1",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Public",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:UserAgent": "test"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

f) Tested using Postman to set the User-Agent in the header and no go

Now the strange thing is .. I've use a similar bucket policy on another bucket and it works great!  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

PS .. haven't added in the IP address check yet, once this is working that'll come next

Comment: Limiting access based on a UserAgent isn't particularly secure -- it is security by obscurity, which isn't guaranteed. Have you considered using Signed URLs instead, or directly calling the S3 APIs rather than using unauthenticated access?

Comment: I'm hoping to proxy web content stored on S3 through NGINX for caching purposes, so that leaves out using the API's.  As for Signed UR's from what I can see they are usually used for uploading content rather than read access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was due to browser caching .. so for every new test I needed to add in a timestamp like so to ensure it wasn't being cached by the browser.

```
http://my-test-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test.html?t=123321
```